# Cómo guardar un archivo en la BBDD en MySQL desde JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, archivo

saludos!. en esta oportunidad les escribo para exponerles una duda hacer de como hacer para guardar un archivo en mi bases de datos MySQL desde JAVA, la cuestión es que este archivo contiene algunas configuraciones de mi sistema y necesito que se almacenen en la BBDD. Luego de investigar varias páginas no he dado con una solución factible a mi problema.

Estoy intentando hacerlo de una manera pero me da un excepción que desconozco. Anexo código a ver si pueden ayudarme a encontrar en que estoy errado.

Para crear mi archivo utilizo el siguiente código (Funciona bien):

```
ObjectOutputStream cal_file = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src/archivos/cal_file.cal"));
            cal_file.writeObject(calibraciones);
            cal_file.close();
```

Ahora para intentar guardarlo en la BBDD de MySQL tengo el siguiente código:

```
File file = new File("src/archivos/cal_file.cal");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
long datos = file.lastModified();
Date fecha = new Date(datos);

Connection accesoBBDD=miConexion.conectar();
PreparedStatement ps = accesoBBDD.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO digitalcal(FechaCal, Nombre, Calibraciones) VALUES('"+fecha.toString()+"', 'Calibraciones', '?')");

ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());

ps.execute();

fis.close();        
ps.close();
accesoBBDD.close();
```

Al intentar ejecutar el código anterior me lanza una excepción en la linea de codigo: `ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());` la cual es la siguiente:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(PreparedStatement.java:3217)
```

De verdad ya no se que hacer si pudieran ayudarme a encontrar el error o indicarme una mejor forma de hacerlo seria genial, Saludos.

Comment: Intenta sin el tercer parámetro: `ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis);`

Comment: Hola Sal, intente lo que me dices y nada!, lo unico que hizo fue cambiar el error, ahora sale esto:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(PreparedStatement.java:3217)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(PreparedStatement.java:5211)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que **'?'** se reconoce como parte de la consulta y no como un parámetro.

**Intenta sin los apóstrofes:**

```
"INSERT INTO digitalcal(FechaCal, Nombre, Calibraciones) VALUES('"+fecha.toString()+"', 'Calibraciones', ?)"
```

Comment: Gracias Paolo, y pss si, era un simple error en la sentencia de la consulta. un error de principiante :) gracias por el apoyo